# How to declare ClassName.FunctionName.myFunction() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, class, oop, undefined

So, I'm trying to access the two functions within the function within a Class. **modal_1()** as shown below in the code. The **console.log("inside 1st");** works fine, but when im trying to go further (  e.g.  modal_1.show_modal_1();  ) it gives me the following error message:

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Modals Class:

```
const Modals = class {
   modal_1(){
        console.log("inside 1st");

        var hide_modal_1 = function () { 
            console.log("hide modal 1");
            //document.getElementById("modal_setup3DScene").style.display = "none"; 
        };
        var show_modal_1 = function() {
            console.log("show modal 1");
            //document.getElementById("modal_1-content").style.display = "block"; 
        };
    }
};
```

What I use to call the Modals Class:

```
let modals_List;
function setup() {
    modals_List = new Modals();
    modals_List.modal_1().show_modal_1();
}
```

Comment: Your `show_modal_1()` function is a local variable of the `modal_1()` method, and will not be visible outside of that method.

Comment: So there is no way that it can be accessed? only by declaring it outside of `modal_1()` but inside of `Class Modals`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not explicitly return something inside the function `modal_1`, so the return value will be `undefined`. Then you are trying to call `show_modal_1()` on `undefined`. Because that property does not exist on it, you get this error.

You can solve it by returning the functions as follows:

```
const Modals = class {
   modal_1() {
        console.log("inside 1st");
        return {
            hide_modal_1: functio () { 
                console.log("hide modal 1");
            },
            show_modal_1: function() {
                console.log("show modal 1");
            }
        }
    }
};
```